# haml use ruby code and plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, plaintext

I'm new with ruby on rails (started today) and I'm using it with haml.

for the purpose of learning I wanted to change the   the application.html.erb on my own to application.html.haml

this was my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HB Combat | <%= @title %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

So I wanted to do the title part in haml but how do I do this the correct way?

what I currently have in the haml code:

```
!!! 5
%html
    %head
        %title HB Combat |
    %body
```

I have tried to type behind the | `=@title` but that didn't work..

So I hope you guys know what I mean to do here! And can help me out with the title part :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple lines to combine plaintext and evaluated code

```
%title
  HB Combat |
  = @title
```

Or use one evaluated String:

```
%title= "HB Combat | #{@title}"
```

**Edit:** As noted by @Unixmonkey, String interpolation also works outside of evaluated code:

```
%title HB Combat | #{@title}
```

Comment: `%title HB Combat | #{@title}` also works in newish versions of Haml

Comment: @Unixmonkey Thanks! Totally forgot that was a feature.